# passing thisArg to a map function

Tags: javascript

This question might already be asked. 
From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), we can pass a `thisVariable` to a map function.

```
var foo=[1,2].map(function(){return this.length},[2,4]); // [2,2]
```

This syntax in ES6, however, returns something else

```
var foo=[1,2].map(_ => this.length ,[2,4]); // [0,0]
```

What is the `[0,0]` returned?

Comment: That is because you're using an arrow function `.. => ...` which preserves the context.

Comment: Per MDN: An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not have its own `this`, `arguments`, `super`, or `new.target`. These function expressions are best suited for non-method functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

Comment: @Titus, I understand that it is related to the fact that `=>` preserves the context. Having said that, does it mean that we cannot achieve the same result with the arrow function ?

Comment: yes. in `map` fun. the second param is `this` value which arrow function will not recognize anyway. to be able to use it, try normal function or function expressions

Comment: @edkeveked Correct, if you want to set the context (to set `this`), you'll need to use a normal function.

Comment: note: should use `let` instead `var`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An arrow function retains the `thisValue` that was in scope in the calling function, it can't be reset. So the `thisValue` argument passed to `map()` is ignored.

So when your uses `this.length`, it's using the value of `this` from the calling context. If you're executing the code at top level (e.g. in the Javascript console), `this == window`, so you're getting the result of `window.length`, which is `0`.